# Changing the background colour of a SwiftUI view adjecent to the tab bar (safe area) changes the tab bar colour?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When setting the background colour of a view adjecent to/touching the tab bar (this also seems to happen with the navigation bar, so perhaps it's a safe area related thing), the tab bar also takes on the colour.

I've verified in the layout inspector that the frame of the view in question is correct.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56568961/4659445) talks about the issue as well, but offers no suggestion on how to fix it.

[image: Issue]
[image: Layout Debugger]

Here's the code for the `Text` element:

```
Text("You are offline. Only media that you have downloaded locally is visible.")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44)
    .background(Color.red)
```

By adding a 1 point tall spacer below the text element, the tab bar is it's normal colour, so it's definitely caused by the `Text` element 'touching' the tab bar.

Anyone know what's going on here and can provide some insight into how to stop this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77620226/5133585 This overload of `background` ignores safe area (which means it extends into the safe area) by default.

Comment: Passing in an explicit `[]` value for the `ignoresSafeAreaEdges` argument did the trick! I find it odd that it defaults to ignoring safe areas but hey... If you write up an answer, I'll accept it.